# How does one define the equivalence of mappings between two sets?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let's say I have two functions $f: A \to B$ and $g: A \to B$. How exactly does one define equivalence between the two functions/mappings?

If $f(a \in A)$ = $g(a \in A)$, then does that imply $f =g$, or do we need stronger/extra conditions?

Comment: $f=g$ simply means that $f(a)=g(a)$ for each $a\in A$; $f=g$ as subsets of $A\times B$,

Answer (score 0):

We have

$f=g$ iff $f(a)=g(a)$ for all $a \in A$